# The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library '/Users/...../platforms/android/CordovaLib/bin/mainactivity-cordovalib.jar'

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

Previously I was using cordova 3.5. I upgraded to 4.3 by using the CLI command. Also upgraded the Android platform. (SDK)
In earlier version it was running fine in Eclipse. But now I am receiving an error which says as follows,

```
The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library '/Users/...../platforms/android/CordovaLib/bin/mainactivity-cordovalib.jar'
```

I have cleaned the projects. Tried to build the mainactivity-cordovalib project first. But the /bin folder is still empty and I am getting the same issue.

Am I missing any steps ?

Comment: Did you import both the project of your app and the project of cordovalib in eclipse?

Comment: yes, I did. Also tried to compile cordovalib project separately with no success

Comment: strange... maybe you checked the "copy projects into workspace" option in eclipse? (I remember getting many errors when I checked that)

Comment: no, success. It is throwing issues

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, did you find any success @nirmal ?

Comment: Same here guys, works fine with previous versions of Cordova

Answer (score 3):

I hit the same issues. Then I found this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-8704.  I then tried the following and got rid of the exact error:

1. Refreshed the project
2. Disabled auto build
3. Cleaned the project
4. Exited Eclipse
5. Restarted Eclipse
6. Built project and it built with no errors!